# Last six months data including blank rows to represent on x-axis graph (ReportBuilder)

Tags: join, report, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi there,

I am trying to fetch last six months data in my query and need to represent 'Month-year' label on x-axis. So query works fine when there is data for a month but if it is unsuccesful in join and no data is returned for that month - there is no label.Hence I am unable to draw it on chart (report Builder 3.0) E.g.

ApptMonthYearname   NotCompleteAppointments AppointmentYear AppointmentMonthInt
January-2012                118                     2012     1
December-2011                88                     2011    12

Query includes a join on three tables and then where clause checks that an appointment is falling between the selected range of month and year or not :

```
declare @SelectedMonth int  
declare @SelectedYear int  
declare @careprovider varchar(20)  
DECLARE @intFlag INT
```

let's say

```
SET @SelectedMonth = 1  
SET @SelectedYear =2012  

declare @selectedDate datetime  
declare @previoussixmonthsdate datetime  

IF (@SelectedMonth = Datepart(mm,GETDate()) and @SelectedYear =Datepart(yyyy,GETDate()))  

BEGIN  
SET @selectedDate = CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(2), datepart(DD,GETDATE())+ '/' + Convert(varchar(2),@SelectedMonth) + '/' +Convert(varchar(4),@SelectedYear), 103))  
SET @previoussixmonthsdate= DATEADD(month, -6, @selectedDate)  

END  

ELSE  

BEGIN  

SET @selectedDate = CONVERT(datetime, '31'+ '/' + Convert(varchar(10),@SelectedMonth) + '/' +Convert(varchar(10),@SelectedYear), 103)  
SET @previoussixmonthsdate= DATEADD(month, -6, @selectedDate)  

END  


select @selectedDate, @previoussixmonthsdate  



SELECT     dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_clinicappointmentid [AppointmentID], 
        dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_statusname [AppointmentStatus], 
        dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime [AppointmentBookingTime],
         Datepart(mm,dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime) [AppointmentMonth],
         Datepart(yyyy,dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime) [AppointmentYear],
         DATENAME(month,dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime) [AppointmentMonthName],
         DATENAME (year,dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime) [AppointmentyearName]


FROM         dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Filteredrbs_clinicinstance ON dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_clinicinstance = dbo.Filteredrbs_clinicinstance.rbs_clinicinstanceid  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Filteredrbs_clinic ON dbo.Filteredrbs_clinicinstance.rbs_clinic = dbo.Filteredrbs_clinic.rbs_clinicid      LEFT OUTER JOIN
                  dbo.Filteredrbs_careproviders ON dbo.Filteredrbs_clinic.rbs_careprovider = dbo.Filteredrbs_careproviders.rbs_careprovidersid

                  WHERE dbo.Filteredrbs_careproviders.rbs_careprovidersid= @careprovider
                  AND dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime <= @selectedDate AND

                   dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime >=@previoussixmonthsdate

                ,dbo.Filteredals_clinicappointment.als_appointmentdatetime)= @SelectedYear

                  GROUP BY YEAR(AppointmentList.AppointmentBookingTime), MONTH(AppointmentList.AppointmentBookingTime)) as [DNAAppts]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One way to guarantee that you always get data for each month in the report range is to populate a temporary/derived table with the set of dates then left join that to the data.

Alternatively you can fake the data eg by storing the results of your query (or a sensible half way stage) into a temporary table then inspect that table to ensure there is data per expected month and if not add it.

Approach 3: union your query with a statement that returns a value for each month expected where there is not real data to match

There are probably even more ways to do this but hopefully that will offer you some inspiration

Comment: Cheers mate. I will try the first one I think.